Wordpress and absolute link paths?
I have been using Wordpress for a very long time in various projects.
Now I have a Wordpress project which has over 9000 articles.
And I use the plugin Link Whisper for the internal link building, which has built up an automatic internal link building of over 125000 links.
I would now like to change this so that I can hopefully get the rules changed to build about 5-10 internal links per article.
But first I want to change the URLs of the articles, category, tags, with permalinkmanager pro and 301 redirects...
But now to my important question:
Why doesn't Wordpress use the IDs of the individual pages, articles, category, tags etc. for internal link building
Why does Wordpress always use absolute link paths?
If I change these paths now, I have to change ALL links in the articles.
TYPO3, for example, always uses the IDs and then converts them into readable URLs in the frontend.
Is there perhaps a plugin or solution that also works with Wordpress?
